# First implementation - Chart object seems to be incomplete

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to implement chart.js (Version: 2.7.3) in my existing site. This is how I do it:

In head section:

```
<script src="../Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In body section:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

})();
</script>
```

When I run this, I get the following JavaScript Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x-axis-0' of undefined at Chart.js:4111
```

I looked it up and the line would do the following:

```
updated[id] = true;
```

with `id` is 'x-axis-0' and `updated` is undefined.

In line 4067 the method `buildOrUpdateScales()` starts do be defined, the beginning looks the following:

```
buildOrUpdateScales: function() {
    var me = this;
    var options = me.options;
    var scales = me.scales || {};
    var items = [];
    var updated = Object.keys(scales).reduce(function(obj, id) {
        obj[id] = false;
        return obj;
    }, {});
    .
    .
    .
```

In my case, `updated` is always undefined, because the property `scales` is missing in `me`/`this`.

I can't understand why that is happening. In the options you can set an option `scales` which I did here by copying the examples, but the `var scales =` is clearly defined as `this.scales` and not `this.options.scales`.

Can anyone explain why that `scales` property could be missing in my `Chart` object? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem `updated is undefined`.

For me, the error happened because of a conflict with an old version of the library `prototypejs`.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJsCanvas"></canvas>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.3/prototype.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      new Chart(document.getElementById('chartJsCanvas').getContext('2d'), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          datasets: [{data:[1,2]}],
        }
      });
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/zedakufimi/edit?html,output

You just have to remove the dependency in the jsbin linked to see the chart being displayed.

New versions doesn't seem to have the conflict.